# Appending String with script tags causes slow loading

Tags: jquery, performance, firefox

We've got the following response from a REST call:

```
{content: "some html here with <script type="text/javascript" src="blah.js"></script>"}
```

We append it to the dom like this:

```
someContainer.html(data.content)
```

Chrome loads these as if it was any other use case, by loading 4 to 6 at a time. Fast.

Firefox only loads them sequentially and it's taking a good 5 or 6 seconds.

What're our options here for making Firefox load these more quickly?
Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the scripts can modify the parse tree using document.write, so you have to run the first one before you know whether to even load the next one if you want the behavior to actually be correct, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Is there anyway to disable this behavior? As noted in the OP, Chrome doesn't do this.

Comment: It's not clear to me that there is while still following the spec, but it's hard to say without a testcase that shows what exactly you're doing.